# Make images take the same height

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm making a grid of 4 images in a row using [DaisyUI](https://daisyui.com/components/card/) card. However some images have white space at the bottom due to different image heights. Is there a way I can make all of them take the same height without compromising image quality?

Here's the code:

```js
import React from "react";

const Book = ({ book }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card card-compact w-56 bg-base-100 shadow-xl">
      <figure>
        <img src={book.img} alt="Books" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Book;
```

I haven't used custom CSS for this. I'm using Tailwind.
Help appreciated!
Here's a snippet: [The yellow book is a good example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9APUK.jpg)

Comment: Not sure if you can apply this in your scenario, but with pure CSS, you can do `height: 100%; object-fit: cover`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use custom CSS, try this:

```css
.card > figure, .card > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card > img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

This will make the `figure` and `img` elements use up 100% of the height and width of their respective containers, and make the `img` element make sure that it will retain its aspect ratio while scaling up.

Comment: ah this sorted the issue! Although I had to apply "h-full w-full" too on the img tag as advised by @Opu down below. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way - This will keep the image size as it is and fill the other area with space, this way all the images will take same specified space regardless of the image size without stretching

```
.img{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;

/*Scale down will take the necessary specified space that is 100px x 100px without stretching the image*/
    object-fit:scale-down;

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this won't solve the issue of the white bars...

Answer (score 0):

- It is possible when you pick images with same aspect ratio.
- You can add `h-full w-full` to make full size image but this will stretch your image in case of height. So, it is better you use images of same aspect ratio.